# How can I write apps for the latest Sony Ericsson phones?

Tags: mobile, devtools

For me in particular it's about Sony Ericsson W715.
What languages can I use and what environment do I need?

A tutorial recommendation would also be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without more information as to what your applications are supposed to do, I would also recommend J2ME, especially given that SonyEricsson has additional useful proprietary APIs that are available to their partners.

You can also target the web browser on the phone by having a server send dynamic HTML and javascript code.

Flash Lite is also an option.

Recent SonyEricsson phones contain the capuchin technology: Write the GUI in Flash and the application engine in J2ME. That could be worth a look, depending on the skills of whoever is working on your applications.

Answer (score 3):

They have a developer page..
http://developer.sonyericsson.com

Answer (score 3):

Your only option would be J2ME. I recommend using [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) with the Mobility Pack for the task. Download the Java version, that includes Java ME.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.thainetbeans.com/sample/mobile.htm) on the net. I am sure you can find many more.

Answer (score 1):

You should use J2ME (Java Micro Edition).